# Cracking effect on a page (non-flash)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a landing page in a website, where there is just a single image of the earth.

Now to enter the main site, I want some effect in the landing page that the earth cracks open and then the user enters the main site.

What I am currently doing: I currently divide the whole landing page image into 4 divs with a separate image in each of them (which jointly form the earth). Now when the user has to enter the site, I simple animate each of the 4 divs to each corner of the screen. But I need cracking effects & some other visually attractive effects.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Javascript (or jQuery) solution preferable.

Comment: Maybe `<canvas>` elements and Voronoi decomposition may help?

Comment: @Blender hm. read about voronoi decomposition for the first time.. difficult to implement in a short span of time. I would wait for another answer, thanks anyways :)

Comment: @NewUser yes its about compatibility. How can you make something flash compatible when the browser doesn't support flash? O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I found my answer combining the other two answers present here.
So am just sharking the fiddle here, so that may be useful in future:

**Updated fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/eC9HM/1/

Comment: So which answer are you going to accept? Your own answer?

Comment: @NewUser none, cause I think all the answers are good & none deserve more credit than the others..

Comment: @gopi1410 it is important to close answered questions. You can do that by selecting you own answer as the accepted one too

Comment: @NewUser had already upvoted both. 
& anyways dont be concerned about upvotes, SO is a Q/A community & you would defeat its purpose if you fight for upvotes. & fyi, there also is a provision for asking a question & answering yourself, the SO way (mentioned at the bottom, each time you ask a question)

Answer (score 2):

- overlay a crack image and make it `slideDown()` (jQuery) over the Earth img.

see http://jsfiddle.net/NKqNh/

```
$(function() {
   $('#crack').slideDown(800); 
});​

<div id="earth" class="common"> </div>
<div id="crack" class="common"> </div>​
```

**Edit**:

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975741/529725) here is an updated js using a callback to an anonymous function for the explosion after the cracking.
http://jsfiddle.net/eC9HM/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#crack').slideDown(800, function() {
      $('#earth, #crack').hide('explode', {pieces: 16}, 2000);
    });
});
​
```

Comment: thanks & I have used both the answers given here in combination: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/eC9HM/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` effect of jQuery UI . It will break the image into many pieces(you can choose how many pieces you want) and The image will disappear

## Uptdated-

Try this code-

```
<html>

<head>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").click(function () {

    $(this).hide("explode", { pieces: 24 }, 2000);

  });

});
</script>

</head>

<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-No5MB366RTY/T3WYGRicqUI/AAAAAAAAALQ/mDgaBLVocZE/s1600/260px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice one!! but would it work on images? The demo they have shown is for html elements like `div`

Comment: I guess I have to divide the image into various parts & put them as background images on a div, then explode them.

Comment: It decomposes your image into square blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/dyg3P/1/

Comment: thanks but I have used both the answers given here in combination: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/eC9HM/1/